# System wide crash when plugging in OEM Bluetooth dongle

Tags: bluetooth

I am a very new Linux user. I have a fresh install of Ubuntu. Yesterday I plugged an OEM Bluetooth dongle to connect my hands free earphones (they worked perfectly at first). But after an hour or two they started having some issues (disconnecting and reconnecting on their own, bad sound quality etc). I unplugged and re-plugged the dongle, it didnt seem to be recognized by my pc. I pressed the "Turn on" bluetooth button, but after half a minute, the system was essentially unresponsive. Terminal commands did nothing, just started a process and stalled on a blank line. I tried opening the system monitor, which had the not responding message repeatedly. When I tried restarting my computer, at the shut down, I had many messages which I can not really understand (images attached). I let the pc open all night and when I woke up, it was still on the same screen, looked like it was stuck on a loop trying to do the same thing over and over again with no result. Lastly, I run the "sudo debsums -sa" command.

My results are

```
debsums: missing file /usr/share/doc/efibootmgr/README.Debian (from efibootmgr package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/doc/efibootmgr/README.gz (from efibootmgr package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/doc/efibootmgr/TODO (from efibootmgr package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/doc/efibootmgr/changelog.Debian.gz (from efibootmgr package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/doc/efibootmgr/copyright (from efibootmgr package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/man8/efibootdump.8.gz (from efibootmgr package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/man8/efibootmgr.8.gz (from efibootmgr package)
```

Does anyone know what is going on? I appreciate your time and help and I apologize for the bad pictures and not so good English.

Error messages at shut down:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BxBldZRaO4lMij9NuY50gRpLMtnGxmL1/view?usp=share_link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BwgzuLADvyriD6rqMTiuKBTE06rJyX-X/view?usp=share_link

System info:
[neofetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgvrg.png)

Thanks again

Comment: I just added the neofetch info screen. If that is not enough, I will add more. Thank you very much

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu? Your errors read like you may not be using Ubuntu.

Comment: @David my ubuntu version is 22.04.02 LTS as you can see in the neofetch screenshot. I am also running dual boot in a partitioned disk

Comment: For some reason your `efibootmgr` package doesn't look to be installed. Confirm that with `apt policy efibootmgr` and install it with `sudo apt install efibootmgr`.

Comment: @Jos turns out i had some efibootmgr packages missing, I installed them and that also seems to have fixed the problem, thank you very much, appreciate your help